# How do you take an initial sample from a flux?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

The [sample](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#sample-java.time.Duration-) operation takes the first entry from flux after the duration.  How can I make it such that I take the first entry on subscribe and then do the rest?

My thinking is that it is something along the lines of [sample with publisher](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#sample-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-) where the publisher sends a signal immediately and followed by intervals, but I am not exactly sure how to go about that.

As I typed the above... I am thinking it is something to do with `Flux.concat(Flux.just(true), Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2)))` for the publisher.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the source `Flux` to a hot one with `2` downstream subscribers:

```
Flux<T> flux = sourceFlux.publish().refCount(2);
```

Then you can create two `Flux` instances, one taking the first item which will be emitted immediately and another that will be skipping the first item then will sample the next values:

```
Flux<T> first = flux.take(1);
Flux<T> rest = flux.skip(1).sample(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
```

You can then merge the two `Flux`es:

```
Flux.merge(first, rest);
```